# Gerar grelha com caracteres aleatórios - java

Tags: java

Pretendo criar uma grelha que seja preenchida aleatoriamente ou com "W" ou "_" e fiz o seguinte:

```
public class Gerador_grelha {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int row = 5;
    int col = 5;
    String[][] grid = new String[row][col];
    String AB = "_W";
    SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(row);
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
            sb.append(AB.charAt(rnd.nextInt(AB.length())));
            sb.toString();
            grid[i][j] = sb.toString();
        }
    }

    for(String[] row:grid) {
        for(String c:row) {
            System.out.print(c);
        }System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Mas neste caso em que seria uma grelha 5 por 5 estou a obter uma assim:

```
WW_W_WW_W_W_W__
_____W__W___W__
__W_WW_WWW_WWW_
__W_WW_WW__WW_W
______________W
```

Que claramente não é 5 por 5. Alguém pode ajudar a resolver o problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto ocorre por que neste trecho:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(row);
for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
    sb.append(AB.charAt(rnd.nextInt(AB.length())));
    sb.toString();
    grid[i][j] = sb.toString();
```

}

Você está concatenando sempre a sobra da iteração anterior, ou seja, na primeira iteração você adiciona `W` ao índice 0, na próxima iteração você adiciona outro carácter a `W` já existente ou seja adiciona `WW` ao índice 2, assim por diante.
Ao final você vai ter uma string em cada índice, não necessáriamente um carácter.

para ajustar você pode simplesmente trocar o trecho q mencionei por isto:

```
for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
    Character c = AB.charAt(rnd.nextInt(AB.length()));
    grid[i][j] = c.toString();
}
```

Agora uma melhor maneira de escrever este código seria ajustando a tipagem do array de `String` para array de `char`:

```
public class Gerador_grelha {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int row = 5;
        int col = 5;
        String AB = "_W";

        char[][] grid = new char[row][col];
        SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();

        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                char c = AB.charAt(rnd.nextInt(AB.length()));
                grid[i][j] = c;
            }
        }

        for (char[] r : grid) {
            for (char c : r) {
                System.out.print(c);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: obrigado, de facto o erro era esse.